# Wordpress ajax conflicts

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have problems with wordpress and ajax.
The ajax request via jQuery just dont work.
Jquery noconflict is enabled and the effects work but the ajax requst dont.
Where could be the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is impossible to answer in its current state I think. Try basic debugging first: Use Firebug to see where the Ajax requests go; use the Firefox error console to see whether any errors come up.

Comment: Thanks. The JS os okay they are no javascript errors, and the requests look fine :/

Comment: Post some sample code, and try to explain a little more what you are attempting to do. Its going to be very difficult to get an answer as the question stands.

Comment: It didnt seems to be my mistake there must be some conflict. I test my code outside wordpress and its working perfectly after i put it in wordpress everthing except jquery.get callback function is working.

Comment: Like @James Wiseman said, "Post some sample code", and also if your Ajax is using the "$" at the beginning of it's statements than try replacing them with just "jQuery". When using WordPress' packaged jQuery library it runs it in noConflict(); mode by default hence the "jQuery".

Answer (score 1):

Post some code, try [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see what's loading/not loading, and this is a good source for info on no-conflitc mode, etc: [5 Tips For Using jQuery with WordPress](http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/)